# Using JSON Log Format from a Python lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to log to CloudWatch using [JSON Log Format](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/01/20/amazon-cloudwatch-logs-json-log-format-support/) from a Python Lambda?

I'd like to create a metrics to monitor data going through my lambda, and [extracting data form JSON Log Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#w2ab1c11c11b9c12c12) seems like a perfect fit.

I'm logging as below:

```
logger.info(dict(items=len(records), max_latency=max_latency))
```

The log shows up on CloudWatch as this:

```
[INFO]  2017-08-04T16:20:23.579Z    some-uuid   {'items': 1, 'max_latency': 1219403.5792706013}
```

But when I try to create a metric with this:

```
{ $.max_latency = * }
```

CloudWatch tells me:

```
Found 0 matches out of 29 event(s) in the sample log.
```

Comment: I am having the same issue in Lambda NodeJS. I am logging JSON event like {message: "this is some error log", level : "Error"}. CloudWatch logs would show the event with prefixed timestamp and uuid, as above. Can you share how you ended up resolving this issue?

Comment: The issue I had was my JSON was not valid JSON. My JSON didn't have "" around keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log entry had 2 problems:

- The JSON generated by Python had single quotes (`'`) for keys instead of double quotes (`"`), CloudWatch only recognizes it if it uses `"`.
- As pointed out by @user615501, the entire log message had to be JSON.

Since lambdas are easily CPU bound and my JSON is super simple, I went with something like this:

```
print('{"items": ' + str(len(records)) + ', "max_latency":' + str(max_latency) + '}')
```

Which outputs:

```
{"items": 1, "max_latency": 1219403.5792706013}
```

It worked, I could successfully filter with `{ $.max_latency = * }` and use `$.max_latency` as the metric value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the issue is that you're providing some JSON formatted data in a syslog format log message.  You probably need to log entirely in JSON, moving the [INFO] tag, timestamp and uuid into the JSON document.

Using basic config you can provide a format parameter that doesn't include data outside the JSON document.

Comment: I think you drew me a picture of why it doesn't work. I can picture how to do that using `boto3` directly, but is it possible to do that with python's `logger` or `print` statements inside the lambda? I'd like to avoid adding calls to CloudWatchLogs API as I figure it would slow down my lambda.

Comment: Try checking out structured logging in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#implementing-structured-logging

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky way to adapt aws_lambda_logging

if you run

```
aws_lambda_logging.setup(level='INFO',aws_request_id='not_a_lambda')
```

at the very top level and dont touch your log configuration after,your logs will automagically appear in json. I'm trying to wrap my head around the innards now to give you a better answer.